# Model not updating accordingly to the subscribe callback in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I'm trying to get 2 components to communicate with each other using a service. The first component adds/deletes entries from a list and adds the accepted ones in a calendar and the 2nd displays them. I've managed to make the list update but I'm having trouble updating the 2nd view, mainly having trouble with removing the rejected entries from the calendar.

**Calendar.service.ts**

```
private someEvents: AgendaEvent[];
  private BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>([])
  private subjectTest: BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>;

      public readAvailableEvents(): Array<AgendaEvent> {
        this.availableEvents = new Array<AgendaEvent>();
        this.someEvents.forEach((element) => {
          if (element.accepted === false) {
            this.availableEvents.push(element);
          }
        });
        return this.availableEvents;
      }

      declineEventById(event: AgendaEvent): Observable<AgendaEvent[]> {
        const index = this.someEvents.indexOf(event);
        this.someEvents.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(this.someEvents);
        this.subject.next(this.readAvailableEvents());
        this.subjectTest.next(this.someEvents);
        return this.subject.asObservable();
      }

      getAgendaEventsData(): Observable<AgendaEvent[]> {
        this.subjectTest.next(this.someEvents);
        console.log(this.someEvents);
        return this.subjectTest.asObservable();
      }
```

**Events.component.ts**

```
     events: AgendaEvent[];
  constructor(
    private calCrud: CalendarCRUDService,
  ) {
    this.calCrud.getAgendaEventsData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.events);
      this.events = data;
      console.log(this.events); });
   }
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. Inside of my HTML, I have my data bound to the events array, and the data returned from the callback is what I want. The only thing that's missing is the view actually updating when I delete an item.
Also, what I'm trying to achieve with this code is notifying different subscribers for different subjects. Hence why there's subject and subjectTest in the code.

Comment: Try `private subject: BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>([])` and same with subjectTest

Comment: I already had that declaration, just forgot to add it to the code snippet

Comment: Try removing `this.subjectTest.next(this.someEvents);` this line from `getAgendaEventsData()` as I don't see any special use of this line here

Comment: It's for my 2nd subject that I have other subscriptions to. To me this simply looks like a changeDetection problem..

Comment: @dobri252 Can u please try my answer?

Comment: I have and there hasn't been any change

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the observable after emitting the data. Please follow this

```
private subjectTest: BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>([]);
public subjectTest$ = this.subjectTest.asObservable();
```

Remove 'return this.subject.asObservable();' in both service methods

**Events.component.ts**

```
this.calCrud.subjectTest$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.events);
      this.events = data;
      console.log(this.events); });
   }
```

Comment: this doesn't solve my issue unfortunately. The declined events still appear in the calendar

Comment: Also, I've noticed that with this change, the first item I delete gets removed from the calendar, but the next ones won't. To me it seems like the changeRef isn't triggered

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add .bind(this) to the end of the subscribe ?

```
this.calCrud.subjectTest$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(this.events);
            this.events = data;
            console.log(this.events); 
}).bind(this);
```

Comment: this just makes the typescript compiler say "Property bind doesn't exist on type subscription"

Comment: i think is right, i can't see the error are you sure that this.subjectTest is not empty?

Comment: Yes, it isn't empty.

Comment: import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'  private  subjectTest = new Subject<any>(); this an example that works in my project , it's quite similar to yours but the differents it's the labrary Subject

Answer (score 0):

Can u try to call the changeDetection explicitly like below

```
  events: AgendaEvent[];
  constructor(
    private calCrud: CalendarCRUDService,private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.calCrud.getAgendaEventsData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.events);
      this.events = data;
      this.cdref.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.events); });
   }
```

Some code suggestions you can try

**Call the method when you delete.this method only send the data.no need to return an observable**

```
getAgendaEventsData(): void {
        this.getSubjectTest.next(this.someEvents);
      }
```

**create reusable method to return your subject**

```
getSubjectTest():BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>{
    return this.subjectTest;
}
```

**subscribe**

```
this.calCrud.getSubjectTest().subscribe(data => {
 this.events = data;

});
```

Comment: I have but there isn't any change in how the model is displayed

Comment: @dobri252 not model change , data in the model.  Ideally it should work.

Comment: I know, sorry juswt a bit tired. but no the data in the model doesn't get updated

Comment: @dobri252 I have added some simple code suggestions , you could try that also.